# Why does Unchanged DatagridViewCheckboxCells throw null exception when i test checked on them?

Tags: c#, .net

My code is throwing null exception and not even going to catch block.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in DGV.Rows)
{
  var cbxCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)r.Cells[0];
  if (cbxCell.Value.ToString() == "true") **<<----- here the exception gets thrown**
  {
     montantFAC = Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
     cmd = new SqlCommand(....);
```

when i test on checked .. it goes throught the checked rows even the unchecked that i checked before and unchecked after. but once it goes to the unchanged checked cells the exception gets thrown.
if you need any more informations let me know . thank you!

This is the exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution!!

i initialized the checkboxes after the datagridview load rows

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in DGV.Rows)
                    {
                        var cbxCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)r.Cells[0];
                        cbxCell.Value = "false";
                    }
```